# How do I add administrator approval on webform submitted data?

Tags: 7, webforms, users

I have the functionality that when any anonymous user submits a webform, then I display the submitted webform data in my new page, but I need admin approval before that submitted data displays on another basic page in Drupal 7.

Does anyone know about admin approval for webform submitted data?

Comment: Given this requirement I would suggest that it'll be a lot easier to meet if instead of using webform to store your data you create a content type for it instead. Then you'll have the ability to use other modules such as those mentioned by @monymirza and [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench).

Comment: i have tried with [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module but my problem is not solved

Comment: It won't solve your problem unless your data is saved as nodes. That's the point.

Comment: hi Alfred Armstrong, can you give me any suggestions for saving webform submitted data as nodes

Comment: You don't need webforms if you have a content type. The normal content type creation form will suffice, you just need to grant the "mytype: Create new content" permission to anonymous users.

Comment: Hi, i have used webform module and with that module created 1 webform for Users Reviews form. after users submit their reviews forms , data is stored in database eith table named  **webform_submitted_data** . i need admin approval for that submitted data , becoz i am displaying that users reviews data on another page. so if any one knows . plz help me. i am stuck in this from last 1 month . thanks in advance .

Comment: How To  grant the "mytype: Create new content" permission to anonymous users

Comment: The same way you grant any permission, at Administration -> People -> Permissions. Find that permission under Node and put a checkbox in the column under anonymous user. You may want to check the column for authenticated user as well, if logged in users are also to use the same form.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a rule that sets a node to unpublished when it is saved. You might also want to have a look at the [Content Approval](http://drupal.org/project/content_approval) module.

> a module that enable the approval of a content (node) by an
>   administrator prior its publication (like the existing feature for
>   comments).

Comment: hi i have used Content Approval module with enabling field " content approval " in webform content type but when webform is submitted , that data is saved in table webform_submitted_data and display in admin side in "webforms" tab for particular webforms with "submissions" tab. but in that i need admin approval like published / unpublished .

Comment: i have tried with all modules like Rules , Workbench , Workbench Moderation , modr8 , moderation , entity , Rules , Workflow with necessary settings from admin side and all configuration . but my problem is still same .  i want admin approval on Webform submitted data . i am searching this problem last 2 days . plz if any one knows help me. thanks in advance. thanks to monymirza

Comment: As has been pointed out, you won't find an answer very easily that way. I suggested taking an alternative approach which should solve the underlying requirement, but if you don't want to follow it that's your choice. Good luck.

Comment: hi Alfred Armstrong , thanks for you help , but can you suggest me some other way by which i can solve my problem . i have tried most of modules , but didn't get exact result.

Comment: hi, i have used 1 module [webform_node_insert](http://ichormedia.com.au/blog/webform-submissions-nodes/) with creating 1 content type webform_node_insert. and assign my webform title with is to this content type but Webform submitted data is not saving as node. but there is no results for my webform submitted . if any one knows plz help me . thanks in advance